# Finding the derivative value at x = 0 of $x|x|$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, absolute-value

please help me with this problem,

I want to find the value of the derivative of the function
$f(x) = x|x|$ at $x=0$

if I'm using the following limit definition

$$\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$$

at $x = 0$ , I get:
$$\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{f(0+\Delta x)-f(0)}{\Delta x} = \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{\Delta x |\Delta x|}{\Delta x} =\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} |\Delta x| = 0$$
but the derivative of $x|x|$ is $\frac{2x^2}{|x|}$ and for $x=0$ I get $\frac{0}{0}$ which is, of course, undefined.

so what is the derivative of $x|x|$ at $x=0$

Thank you

Comment: Your first answer is the correct answer

Comment: are you sure derivative exists at 0?

Comment: The above shows that the derivative exists at $x=0$.

Comment: Also $\frac{2x^2}{\lvert x\rvert}=\frac{2\lvert x\rvert^2}{\lvert x\rvert}=2\lvert x\rvert$

Comment: The latter formula only holds for $x\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The function is actually differentiable at $x = 0$ and the derivative is indeed equal to $0$.
Note that,
$$x|x| = \begin{cases} 
x^2 & \text{for } x \ge 0 \\
-x^2 & \text{for } x < 0
\end{cases}
$$
Thus,
$$(x|x|)' = \begin{cases} 
2x & \text{for } x \ge 0 \\
-2x & \text{for } x < 0
\end{cases}
$$
This clearly gives us, $(x|x|)' = 0$  at $x = 0$.
The formula you stated, as said in the comments, only works when $x \ne 0$.